# How to make remote jquery validation for tied fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Let's say I have couple of input fields - their combination must be unique.
Each of them causes remote validation method triggering - and it's the same method for both fields. If combination is unique - it returns true.
The problem is following: when after validation error I change the field, that is not marked as erroneous, the erroneous field keeps being considered erroneous, even if method returns true (the couple is unique)!

I even don't need to make extra request to server, because the couple is unique! I just need to clear error for field, marked erroneous. However, I have not managed to do this - seems like jquery does not offer functionality for this.

Any ideas?

The relevant code is pretty huge, but the key parts are here:

```
this.clearErrors = function ($elements) {
    var $validator = $elements.first().closest('form').validate();
    $elements.each(function(index, item) {
        var $parent = $(item).parent();
        var element = $(item).get(0);
        if ($parent.is('td')) {
            $parent.removeClass(window.resources.errorCellClass);
        }
        $parent.find('span.' + window.resources.errorSpanClass).remove();
        $validator.successList.push(element);
        delete $validator.invalid[element.name];
        delete $validator.submitted[element.name];
    });
};

//Fixing remote method, since original one returned "pending" status all the time, as reported in other stackoverflow question
    $.validator.addMethod('synchronousRemote', function (value, element, param) {
        if (this.optional(element)) {
            return 'dependency-mismatch';
        }

        var previous = this.previousValue(element);
        if (!this.settings.messages[element.name]) {
            this.settings.messages[element.name] = {};
        }
        previous.originalMessage = this.settings.messages[element.name].remote;
        this.settings.messages[element.name].remote = previous.message;

        if (typeof param == 'string') {
            param = { url: param }
        }

        if (previous.old === value) {
            return previous.valid;
        }

        previous.old = value;
        var validator = this;
        this.startRequest(element);
        var data = {};
        data[element.name] = value;
        var valid = 'pending';
        $.ajax($.extend(true, {
            url: param,
            async: false,
            mode: 'abort',
            port: 'validate' + element.name,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {
                validator.settings.messages[element.name].remote = previous.originalMessage;
                valid = response === true || response === 'true';
                if (valid) {
                    var submitted = validator.formSubmitted;
                    validator.prepareElement(element);
                    validator.formSubmitted = submitted;
                    validator.successList.push(element);
                    delete validator.invalid[element.name];
                    validator.showErrors();
                } else {
                    var errors = {};
                    var message = response || validator.defaultMessage(element, 'remote');
                    errors[element.name] = previous.message = $.isFunction(message) ? message(value) : message;
                    validator.invalid[element.name] = true;
                    validator.showErrors(errors);
                }
                previous.valid = valid;
                validator.stopRequest(element, valid);
            }
        }, param));
        return valid;
    });

    $root.filter(':input[data-excluded-values-method]:not([readonly])').add($root.find(':input[data-excluded-values-method]:not([readonly])')).each(function () {
        var $element = $(this);
        $element.validate({
            onkeyup: false
        })
        var $entityContainer = $element.closest('[data-entity]');
        var $keyFields = $entityContainer.filter('INPUT[data-is-key]:not([disabled])').add($entityContainer.find('INPUT[data-is-key]:not([disabled])'));
        var localizedNames = [];
        $keyFields.each(function () {
            localizedNames.push($(this).attr('localized-name'));
        });
        $element.rules('add',
        {
            synchronousRemote: function () {
                var key = [];
                var keyIsUnique = true;
                $keyFields.each(function () {
                    key.push($(this).val());
                });
                return {
                    url: $element.attr('data-excluded-values-method'),
                    type: 'POST',
                    async: false,
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        key: key,
                        entityType: $entityContainer.attr('data-entity')
                    }),
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    dataFilter: function (isUnique) {
                        keyIsUnique = isUnique;
                        return isUnique;
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        if (keyIsUnique === 'true') {
                            window.commonUtils.clearErrors($keyFields.filter('[name!="' + $element.attr('name') + '"]:input[data-excluded-values-method]:not([readonly])'));
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            messages: {
                synchronousRemote: $.validator.format(window.resources.notUniqueValidationError)(localizedNames.join(' + '))
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: People, please, stop downvoting! If you have nothing to say - just pass by! I've tried to describe my question as short as possible so it was easier to grasp the problem for you. Later, i've added code and even added the solution that worked for me. NEVERTHELESS, someone very clever keeps downvoting... Hell knows what.

Comment: Actually this was very useful to me. Almost all the questions relating to this, here, are about "rules", where as this is about a "method". I fully understand the difference, but sometimes you need a method not a rule, for reasons irrelevant to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've debugged jquery validate method and found what yet should be set to clear validation error:

```
$validator.previousValue(element).valid = true;
```

Now everything works.

Comment: So the answer appears to be that if you need to use a remote method (not a rule), then you need to hack the relevant rule code out of the plugin and re-use it verbatim. If you miss one or more of the magic incantations there you stuff up the error handling.

Comment: *philw* - yes, looks like jquery needs something to be hacked in some cases to make things work. Once bumped into another issue in jquery lib and decided to upgrade to latest version. Result: it turned out, that required functionality was not implemented at all yet there. So I had to rollback and patch some methods with my prototype :)